# Get back the assembly level code from exe files?

Tags: assembly

I was doing linux assembly programming and for the past few days I have switched to learn windows assembly programming. I am using `ml` as my assembler and `golink` as my linker. I have my assembly code and have obtained my `exe` from it. Now I need to get back its hex like `\xff\xab\x55` and so on. In linux I used `objdump -d elf_executable` or `xxd -i file`. What is its windows equivalent ?

**Edit**
I need to mention that with objdump on windows I am getting the following error

```
C:\Arena>objdump -d a.exe                                                                                                                                                 
objdump: a.exe: File format not recognized
```

After compiling it with

```
C:\Arena>ml a.asm
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 10.00.30319.01                                                                                                                      
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.                                                                                                                

 Assembling: a.asm  
C:\Arena>golink a.obj kernel32.dll user32.dll                                                                                                                             

GoLink.Exe Version 0.26.14 - Copyright Jeremy Gordon 2002/9 - JG@JGnet.co.uk                                                                                              
Output file: a.exe                                                                                                                                                        
Format: win32 size: 1,536 bytes
```

Comment: I dont know the microsoft tools equivalent but you certainly can use gnu tools on windows and I assume as a result use gnu objdump.  Perhaps gnu objdump works on exe files whomever created them.

Comment: `a.exe` probably is not an executable. It might be an object file. `ml` is assembler, witch generates object file, check the first two bytes of that `a.exe` in some hex editor, if there are not `MZ`, then it's not an executable. You need to link it using `link` or assemble with `ml a.asm /link /entry:YOUR_ENTRY /subsystem:console kernel32.lib more_libs.lib ...`

Comment: No no I did link the obj file. See my edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used the program *dumppe.exe* before for disassembly.

By typing;

```
where dumppe
```

for me *dumppe.exe* turns out to be in the same directory as *ml.exe*; *masm32\bin\dumppe.exe*

for a rough disassembly you can enter;

```
dumppe -quiet -disassem [file-name-here]
```

alternatively you could enter;

```
dumppe -quiet -disassem:![lable-here] [file-name-here]
```

or for more info just type "*dumppe*" at the cmd prompt.

I also have a windows version of [grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) installed on my windows and when i use the cmd

```
dumppe -disassem -quiet win.exe | grep -A10 start:
```

I get;

```
00401000                    start:
00401000 6A00                   push    0
00401002 680F304000             push    offset off_0040300F     ; 'program statment!!!',000h
00401007 6800304000             push    offset off_00403000     ; 'hello world!!!',000h
0040100C 6A00                   push    0
0040100E E80D000000             call    jmp_MessageBoxA
00401013 6A00                   push    0
00401015 E800000000             call    jmp_ExitProcess

0040101A                    jmp_ExitProcess:            ; Xref 00401015
0040101A FF2500204000           jmp     dword ptr [ExitProcess]
```

a comparasin to when i use *objdump*

```
objdump -M intel -D win.exe | grep -A10 text.:
```

which is pretty much the same as

```
objdump -M intel -d win.exe
```

I get;

```
00401000 <.text>:
  401000:       6a 00                   push   0x0
  401002:       68 0f 30 40 00          push   0x40300f
  401007:       68 00 30 40 00          push   0x403000
  40100c:       6a 00                   push   0x0
  40100e:       e8 0d 00 00 00          call   0x401020
  401013:       6a 00                   push   0x0
  401015:       e8 00 00 00 00          call   0x40101a
  40101a:       ff 25 00 20 40 00       jmp    DWORD PTR ds:0x402000
  401020:       ff 25 08 20 40 00       jmp    DWORD PTR ds:0x402008
```

Comment: thanks !!! That was quite helpful, but you seem to be getting objdump working right on windows. Can you please post how you assembled and linked your code ???

Comment: sure, for this particular program i used the commands; `ml /c /coff win.asm` & `link /subsystem:windows win.obj`

Comment: No worries and that's great it worked! i'm glad i was able to help.

Answer (score 9):

If you have Visual Studio installed, you can use [DUMPBIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756as972):

```
dumpbin /DISASM /out:log.txt file.exe
```

Comment: +1 That worked like charm, Feels good to work with windows native applications, but I don need to get the complete dump which it lists. I would like to have only the executable part of the hex ie the exact equivalent of the `objdump -d` not the `objdump -D` which has all the sections along with the executable code making it difficult to get the executable part only.

Comment: I crosschecked it but still get the complete code instead of getting only the executable part. Can you please post a sample output with your answer, It will really be of great help to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can have `objdump` on Windows, install [`MinGW`](http://www.mingw.org/), it's shipped with it among other tools:

```
> dir /b \MinGW\bin
addr2line.exe
ar.exe
as.exe
c++.exe
c++filt.exe
cc.exe
cpp.exe
dlltool.exe
dllwrap.exe
elfedit.exe
g++.exe
gcc.exe
gcov.exe
gdb.exe
gdbserver.exe
gprof.exe
ld.bfd.exe
ld.exe
libexpat-1.dll
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libgmp-10.dll
libgomp-1.dll
libiconv-2.dll
libintl-8.dll
libmpc-2.dll
libmpfr-1.dll
libquadmath-0.dll
libssp-0.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
mingw-get.exe
mingw-get.exe~
mingw32-c++.exe
mingw32-cc.exe
mingw32-g++-4.6.2.exe
mingw32-g++.exe
mingw32-gcc-4.6.2.exe
mingw32-gcc.exe
mingw32-make.exe
mingwm10.dll
nm.exe
objcopy.exe
objdump.exe
pkginfo.exe
pthreadGC2.dll
quserex-test.exe
ranlib.exe
readelf.exe
size.exe
strings.exe
strip.exe
windmc.exe
windres.exe

>
```

[Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/) it and installed, then setup the environment variables, see [Environment Settings](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started#toc7) part on the [Getting Started](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started) page.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind that these tools only operate with GUI (afaik),
check out **IDA Pro** (static), **OllyDbg**(dynamic), they display the instructions, and the opcodes.